# reading formatted input in matlab

Tags: matlab, io

I am trying to read a file with 5 entries for each line, two of which are float and the others are integers. However, fscanf function of matlab only reads two rows, and I guess it's a memory problem (for just 5k lines of data?).

Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt its a memory problem.
Maybe you have some unexpected characters in your input file?
Can you reproduce the following?

## input.txt

```
3.4E-5 4.2E14 1475 381 998877
3.4E-5 4.2E14 1475 381 998877
3.4E-5 4.2E14 1475 381 998877
3.4E-5 4.2E14 1475 381 998877
3.4E-5 4.2E14 1475 381 998877
```

## end input.txt

```
filename='input.txt';
fid = fopen(filename);
A = fscanf(fid, '%f %f %d %d %d', [5 inf])';
fclose(fid);


>> A(:,1)

ans =

  1.0e-004 *

    0.3400
    0.3400
    0.3400
    0.3400
    0.3400

>> A(:,5)

ans =

    998877
    998877
    998877
    998877
    998877
```

Just be careful because I'm pretty sure everything numeric gets clobbered to double when using fscanf with multiple numeric types.

```
>> class(A(:,5))

ans =

 double
```

Comment: Couple of minor errors here.  A = fscanf('%f ... should be A = fscanf(fid, '%f ... ; and this approach puts the transpose of the input table into A.